# MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException C# connection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this code based on a mongodb connection example, I am trying to insert an object.
but getting and error on the insertone line

This is the error data:
*MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: 'Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.'
Inner 
MongoCommandException: Command saslContinue failed: bad auth Authentication failed..*

I am new using mongodb and got no idea of what is the error reason.
Any help

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://dbUser:dbPass001@cluster0-pfry9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("test");

            var collection = database.GetCollection<anyClassTest>("entities");
            var r = new anyClassTest() { name="Original", edad = 36, id = 1};
            collection.InsertOne(r);
        }

        public class anyClassTest
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int edad { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standalone, direct connections, create the client the following way,

```
    var servers = new List<MongoServerAddress>() { new MongoServerAddress("hostname", 27017) };
    var credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", "user", "pass");
    var mongoClientSettings = new MongoClientSettings()
    {
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
        Credential = credential,
        Servers = servers.ToArray(), 
        ApplicationName = "NameOfApp",
    };

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
```

Once you have the client (connected), then you can get the database / collections and do what you need.

```
var database = client.GetDatabase("dbname");
var collection = database.GetCollection<anyClassTest>("entities");
var r = new anyClassTest() { name="Original", edad = 36, id = 1};
collection.InsertOne(r);
```

Comment: I am trying to connect to Atlas MongoDb, I am using the connection string from the web site example. there is no issue connecting or getting the database. the error is raised on the insertone line specifically.

Comment: Your error is very specific to Authentication. If you are not authenticating correctly, you will not be able to perform actions (Search / Insert / Update / Delete)

Comment: You are completely right, it was my mistake. I was confused because the getdabase and getcollection thrown no exceptions, so I was thinking there was no issue with authentication. but you are right, I guess those methods does not validate these things. Thanks